# How should I use COUNT()?

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to get a count of the AgentID field in the leadsrecived table and leadstep field from the leads proposed table.  These counts should be by date for each employee.

I would like the query results to return the following fields:

- Date
- EmployeeLastName
- EmployeeFirstName
- Count of AgentID
- Count of Leadstep

I have run the query individually and can get the right count but when I try to combine the counts in to one query the counts are not correct.

Table #1: Employees

```
AgentID              AgentFirstName              AgentLastName
12345                     John                       Smith
67891                     Jim                        Jones
```

Table #2: Leads Received

```
Acctdate                  AgentID
9/1/2013                   12345
9/1/2013                   12345
9/1/2013                   12345
9/1/2013                   67891  
9/1/2013                   67891  
9/1/2013                   67891  
9/1/2013                   67891
```

Table #3: Leads Proposed

```
Acctdate                    AgentID                  Leadstep
9/1/2013                    12345                      ABC
9/1/2013                    12345                      ABC
9/1/2013                    12345                      DEF
9/1/2013                    12345                      DEF
9/1/2013                    12345                      DEF
9/1/2013                    67891                      DEF
9/1/2013                    67891                      DEF
9/1/2013                    67891                      DEF
9/1/2013                    67891                      ABC
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
SELECT [Leads Received].ACCTGDATE, 
    Employees.AgentLastName, 
    Employees.AgentFirstName, 
    Count([Leads Proposed].LEADSTEP) AS CountOfLEADSTEP, 
    Count([Leads Received].AgentID) AS CountOfAgentID
FROM Employees 
INNER JOIN [Leads Proposed] 
    ON Employees.AgentID = [Leads Proposed].AgentID) 
INNER JOIN [Leads Received] ON 
    [Leads Proposed].ACCTGDATE = [Leads Received].ACCTGDATE 
    AND Employees.AgentID = [Leads Received].AgentID
GROUP BY [Leads Received].ACCTGDATE, 
    Employees.AgentLastName, 
    Employees.AgentFirstName;
```

Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to make it more meaningful. "SQL Query - NEED HELP - PLEASE" is not something that will be useful in a search by future readers, and it's clear you need help or you wouldn't be asking here. :-) While you're at it, you can add a tag that indicates what DBMS you're using, and remove the "database" tag. (It's clear it's a database question, because it's about SQL.) Thanks.

Comment: `COUNT(column)` just gives you a row-count for non-null instances of that column.  You likely want `COUNT(DISTINCT [Leads Proposed].LEADSTEP)` although I'm not sure you've set yourself up with distinct values to help you do this...

Comment: Leads Proposed is a table.  I never said it was a column.

Comment: neither did anyone else...

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
SELECT  allComb.AcctDate
    , Employees.AgentLastName
    , Employees.AgentFirstName
    , lr.agentCount
    , lp.leadCount
FROM Employees
--get a list of all unique Agent and Date Combinations for both tables
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AcctDate, AgentId
    FROM LeadsReceived
    UNION
    SELECT AcctDate, AgentId
    FROM LeadsProposed
) AS allComb
ON employees.AgentId = allComb.AgentId
--Get the agent count from LeadsRecieved
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AgentId, AcctDate, COUNT(AgentId) AS agentCount
    FROM LeadsReceived
    GROUP BY AgentId, AcctDate
) AS lr
ON employees.AgentId = lr.AgentId
AND allComb.AcctDate = lr.AcctDate
--Get the LeadStep Count from LeadsProposed
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AgentId, AcctDate, COUNT(Leadstep) AS leadCount
    FROM LeadsProposed
    GROUP BY AgentId, AcctDate
) AS lp
ON employees.AgentId = lp.AgentId
AND allComb.AcctDate = lp.AcctDate
```

Comment: But oh so simpler if only there were auto-increment ids...  Where's the group by employeeid/date?  "These counts should be by date for each emplopyee."    ... oh wait, hmm you're not grouping at all, letting the joins expand OK.

Comment: you need AcctDate in your `join` conditions

Comment: just made an edit, thanks for the comments. Definitely agree on the AutoIncremented Id's.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't first union also have to be grouped at some point since the tables have multiple rows for each date?

Comment: The AgentID is an employee id.  I do have have an autoincremented PK assigned as well.

Comment: @ebyrob once again, good point. That should be a union not union all to ensure a distinct set of values.

Comment: @cdlong to be fair, I couldn't remember if a union was equivalent to distinct on both tables prior to combining.  (I just knew the second set would have values skipped if present but couldn't remember if the first set would be collapsed if it had dupes)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ADATE AS ACCTGDATE,
    Employees.AgentLastName,
    Employees.AgentFirstName,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEADSTEP) FROM [Leads Proposed]
       -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Leads Proposed]  -- or maybe this
        WHERE [Leads Proposed].AgentID = AID
          AND [Leads Proposed].Acctdate = ADATE
    ) AS CountOfLEADSTEP,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Leads Received]
       WHERE [Leads Received].AgentID = AID
         AND [Leads Received].Acctdate = ADATE
    ) AS CountOfAgentID
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AgentID AS AID, Acctdate AS ADATE FROM [Leads Proposed]
  UNION
  SELECT AgentID AS AID, Acctdate AS ADATE FROM [Leads Received]
) AS a ON AgentID = AID
GROUP BY ADATE, AID
```

With auto-increment IDs the query becomes:

```
SELECT
    [Leads Proposed].AcctDate AS ACCTGDATE,
    Employees.AgentLastName,
    Employees.AgentFirstName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Leads Proposed].ID) AS CountOfLEADSTEP,
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Leads Received].ID) AS CountOfAgent
FROM Employees
JOIN [Leads Proposed] ON [Leads Proposed].AgentID = Employees.AgentID
JOIN [Leads Received] ON [Leads Received].AgentID = Employees.AgentID
                     AND [Leads Proposed].AcctDate = [Leads Received].AcctDate
GROUP BY Employees.AgentID, [Leads Proposed].AcctDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT COALESCE(t3.AcctDate1, t3.AcctDate2), Employees.AgentLastName, Employees.AgentFirstName, 
        t3.CountOfLEADSTEP, t3.CountOfAgentID
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT COALESCE(t1.AgentID, t2.AgentID) AS AgentID, t1.AcctDate AS AcctDate1, t1.CountOfAgentID, t2.AcctDate as AcctDate2, t2.CountOfLEADSTEP
    FROM
    (SELECT AcctDate, AgentID, Count([LeadsReceived].AgentID) AS CountOfAgentID FROM [LeadsReceived] GROUP BY AcctDate, AgentID) as t1
        FULL JOIN (SELECT AcctDate, AgentID, Count([LeadsProposed].LEADSTEP) AS CountOfLEADSTEP FROM [LeadsProposed] GROUP BY AcctDate, AgentID) as t2
        ON t1.AgentID = t2.AgentID AND t1.ACCTDATE = t2.ACCTDATE) AS t3
ON Employees.AgentID = t3.AgentID
```

From the sample you have provided I added an additional row on LeadsReceived for Agent 1234 for a different date and an additional row on Leads Proposed for the same agent for yet another date and the above query produced the following results which I think is what you are looking for.

```
2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 Smith   John    5   3
2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 Jones   Jim 4   4
2013-09-05 00:00:00.000 Smith   John    1   NULL
2013-09-20 00:00:00.000 Smith   John    NULL    1
```